# Script to remove "People you may know" on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there a userscript / greasemonkey script that can remove the `People you may know` section from Facebook?

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend using **[Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/)**. It's an addon for Firefox, similar to Greasemonkey. But instead of adding custom scripts, it adds custom CSS.

Once installed, add this style to Stylish:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("facebook.com") {
  #pagelet_netego {display: none;}
}
```

This should take care of your "People you may know" box situation.

Enjoy.

Comment: By the way, you can find some interesting and helpful styles at http://userstyles.org/

Comment: Including `.ego_unit { display: none; }` as well seemed to clean up some more of the related elements

Answer (score 3):

There's a script [to remove the entire sidebar on the right,](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/80573) including the *people you may know* box.

Comment: This one removes the ego_bar : http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/134641

Comment: both those links are dead

Comment: @macknordstrum I'm afraid we can't do much about it.  I have gotten rid of the completely wrong answer, but perhaps someone can hunt down where these scripts moved to.  Otherwise, if you come across a working answer, please add it to the mix!

Comment: I don't know if something like this would work. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fb-purity-cleans-up-facebook/

Answer (score 2):

I have tried BNn, Fczbkk's suggestions and neither solved the problem. Gelatin's mentioned script seems to work but impacts the main window too-you can't see the list of people who clicked on "like" on a post. I have also tried [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080621140431AAxcbXv) idea to repeatedly click on x's. They disappear momentarily but then again appear next day.

What worked for me is to install the Firefox add on [FB Purity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fb-purity-cleans-up-facebook).
It cleans up the sponsored page, the People you may know and has settings on what you want to appear on Facebook page. I will update my answer if it stops working.

Comment: **@Theta30** thanks theta for sharing about FB Purity. i feel so relieved now :)

Comment: @mack I hadn't noticed that the add-in was already in this answer, sorry.  Does it work?

Comment: the version linked to on addons.mozilla.org is out of date, and won't hide the people you may know box, the latest version is on the fbpurity.com website, and does hide the people you may know box.

Answer (score 0):

Try  [this Userscripts script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/47692).

> **Script Summary:** Removes "People You May Know" ("Suggestions") from Facebook homepage. Works in the new design.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: the link in this answer is dead

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the 'Add people you know page' and go straight to your Facebook page.

It can be done quickly and without difficulty in Windows. You just need to create an Icon once as set out below.

1. Log into Facebook, then select your profile page.
2. Copy the URL that relates to that page, it will start 'hpps' and have your name towards the end.
3. Right click on an empty part of Windows Explorer and select New - Shortcut
4. In the 'Type location of the item' box paste the address above, click 'Next'
   then enter a name for the shortcut, eg 'Facebook'.
5. The shortcut will appear as an Icon on your Explorer page.
6. In future access Facebook using this Icon.
7. If you are not logged in a page will open stating "This content is currently unavailable'. Just enter your email address and password in the boxes, and press the Return key.

Facebook will now always open at your Profile Page, and bypass 'Add people you know'

'Simples', LOL

Comment: this doesn't eliminate the "People You May Know" boxes that appear to the right hand side of the newsfeed and directly in the newsfeed

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extension that removes People you may know: [Remove People You May Know from Facebook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remove-people-you-may-kno/fgjpligalfibefninpikimdbpihgpblh)

Answer (score 0):

In [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/), [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) or a similar browser extension that can use AdBlock Plus filter lists, installing or subscribing to the [Facebook Annoyances Blocker list](http://facebook.adblockplus.me/en/) will block the 'People You May Know' section among other Facebook annoyances.